# Hiding a class in C# using interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a class called `ResponseBuffer` which reads and write into the buffer. I want to hide this class and want to provide only the `Read()` and `Write()` APIs to the other classes.

I am planning to use an `interface` for this purpose. I have written the following sample MWE code.

```
//*************************************************
//-----Response Buffer (Should be HIDDEN class)
//*************************************************
interface IResponseBuffer
{
    void ReadResponseBuffer();
    void WriteResponseBuffer(string message);
}
class ResponseBuffer : IResponseBuffer //HIDE THIS CLASS
{
    private BlockingCollection<string> ResponseBuffer = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public void ReadResponseBuffer()
    { }
    public void WriteResponseBuffer(string message)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}


//*************************************************
//-----Communication Channel Class - This class needs to use the Response Buffer APIs
//*************************************************
class CommunicationChannel
{
    IResponseBuffer _objResposeBuffer;

    public void SetResponseBufferObject(IResponseBuffer objResponseBuffer)
    {
        this._objResposeBuffer = objResponseBuffer;
    }

    public void StartCommunication()
    {
        _objResposeBuffer .WriteResponseBuffer("Hello");
    }
}

//*************************************************
//-----Main Entry Point for the Program
//*************************************************
class MainWindow_EntryPoint
{        
    ResponseBuffer _objResponseBuffer = new ResponseBuffer();

    CommunicationChannel _objComChannel = new CommunicationChannel();

    //Main enter Constructor
    public MainWindow_EntryPoint()
    {            
        _objComChannel.SetResponseBufferObject(_objResponseBuffer);
        _objComChannel.StartCommunication();
    }
}
```

**Code Explanation:** In the code above, I have a `ResponseBuffer` class, which implements the Read and Write methods to modify the buffer queue. I want to hide this class using an interface called `IReposnseBuffer`, which provides the APIs 
 called `ReadReposneBuffer` and `WriteReposnseBuffer`.

**PROBLEM:** Though the `ComminicationChannel` class has no knowledge about the `ReponseBuffer` class still, I have to create an object of the `ReponseBuffer` class in the `Main`.

How can I use the methods of `ReposeBuffer` class without creating any of its objects directly?

Comment: You can't. The methods you want to use are instance methods, so you need an instance. If it doesn't introduce any problems, you could make the instance methods static methods...

Comment: @Kit: Is my implementation of Interface correct? If I am already creating an object of class  `ReponseBuffer` in the `main` then I am exposing its members and the whole purpose of using an interface is lost...isn't it?

Comment: No, you are not exposing the object. You are passing the interface into `CommunicationChannel`, which because it's coded to use the interface, doesn't know that the methods are implemented on `ResponseBuffer`. What you have is fine.

Comment: Look up software patterns, in particular the factory pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory class that returns instances of `IResponseBuffer`. Your factory class could then return your implementation of that interface (the "hidden" class). Then your calling code only needs to know of the interface and the factory while your factory could return anything that implements that interface.